# Javascript functions not defined error if page loaded using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

The functions are defined. And they are working fine. In the original page (with no ajax) the case is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
callA();    
}); 

</script>


<script>
function  callA(){..}
</script>
```

It works fine in this case. But if the same page is called using ajax it says that

```
callA  is not defined
```

in firebug console.

Am I missing anything? If it should not work then how is this working in first case?

Please help.

Edit: this is how it is called.

```
$.ajax({
 url:selectedPortletURL,
 method: "GET",
 success: function(data)
 {

    $("#searchCriteriaDiv").html(data);
},
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert("error:" + textStatus + " - exception:" + errorThrown);
 }
});
```

Comment: It is much easier to identify problems when you show us the code that *doesn't* work instead of some other code that *does* work.

Comment: How is the page called in the ajax case?

Comment: even the way you have it there is wrong.  Your definitions should always come before the place where you use it.  put your definition (`function callA(){}`) in a <head> script tag.  and then show us the code for the ajax portion

Comment: Hi Quentin.. thanks for reply.. I can definitely not show the original one, i hope you understand that is against any company policy. But still, this is the scenario which is exactly as original.

Comment: Hi Ravi, great policy that you can't show the snippet which is BTW not working :D.

Comment: Hi ps2goat, Please check my last edit. I agree to you and even I always thought that it should be defined before. but its working fine if not called by ajax on FF.

Comment: Yup man.. :) strange yet can't show. Its a jsp that's called by a portlet. Its a search criterion to get the data from db. I just copied the jsp to another portlet just to copy the criterion and loading it dynamically via ajax and its not working properly. The problem is if it was just one function or two, fine. But there are more than 15-20 functions and their calls to track.. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery `ready` event fires when the document is ready (or as soon as a function is attached to it if the document is already ready).

Since you are adding your script elements to the document after the document is ready, that is immediately.

The first script element gets parsed first. The ready handler fires. `callA` is not defined.

Then the second script element gets parsed. `callA` is defined, but too late.

---

You need to refactor your code. At a minimum, I'd put everything for a given page into a single script. Ideally, I'd rewrite it so that all the JS was separated out into a script file and Ajax was used to load structured data instead of HTML documents.

Answer (score 1):

<del>`$(document).ready()` will not fire if contained inside an AJAX response, as it is only triggered when the original document first loads.</del>

Loading dynamic `<script>` tags via AJAX isn't recommended. You should try to put the code in traditional javascript files, and use a callback.

Comment: Yup.. its firing all over jsp.. ;) there is a code written to modify the ids of the jsp based on <portlet:namespace/>